# Pointer to member template classes

Tags: c++

AbstractFieldCollection is the base class of hardwareMissingAlarm, etc.
hardwareMissingAlarm belongs to another class that is a template.

```
alarmFieldCollection.push_back((AbstractAlarmField Device::*)  &Device::hardwareMissingAlarm);
alarmFieldCollection.push_back((AbstractAlarmField Device::*)  &Device::hardwareErrorAlarm);
alarmFieldCollection.push_back((AbstractAlarmField Device::*)  &Device::badConfigAlarm);``
```

Then in another function I'm reading the vector like this:

```
for(int32_t i=0; i<alarmFieldCollection.size(); i++) 
{
    AbstractAlarmField Device::* pAF = alarmFieldCollection[i];
    std::cout << "isRaised: "<< pDev << std::endl;
    if ((pDev->*pAF).isRaised(pContext))
    {
           .....
    }
 }
```

and `pDev` is the Device object, however `pDev->*pAF` returns `NULL`. In fact when I'm printing `&Device::hardwareErrorAlarm`, `&Device::hardwareMissingAlarm`  the result is 1. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

`isRaised` is a method that belongs to the `class AbstractAlarmField`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where and how is `pDev` defined`?

Comment: Why do you cast the pointer to member functions? If they are truly of the right type, this is not necessary.

Comment: void execute(RequestEvent* pEvt, Device* pDev, Alarm_DataType& data) that is the header. pDev is the Device that has all the fields including the alarms. AbstractAlarmField is the abstract class of AlarmField. AlarmFields are templates so cannot be instantiated when you are getting the field from the collection, because of that I'm trying to get it casting to the Abstract class

Comment: "AbstractFieldCollection is the base class of hardwareMissingAlarm, etc." Is this correct or is `AbstractAlarmField` the base class of hardwareMissingAlarm?

Answer (score 2):

You provided almost no code but it seems like you are storing an abstract object by value, not by reference or pointer. This may lead to object slicing and any kind of memory problem as a consequence. Try to use `AbstractAlarmField&` as the type of `Device` fields instead.

Comment: void execute(RequestEvent* pEvt, Device* pDev, Alarm_DataType& data) that is the header. pDev is the Device that has all the fields including the alarms. AbstractAlarmField is the abstract class of AlarmField. AlarmFields are templates so cannot be instantiated when you are getting the field from the collection, because of that I'm trying to get it casting to the Abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

It is not useful to convert a member pointer `X C::*` to `Y C::*`.  The Standard allows it as a `reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast, but with entirely unspecified results (unless you convert back to the original type).  You would be better off using a virtual functor to safely get the `AbstractAlarmField` subobject:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

struct AlarmGetter {
public:
    virtual ~AlarmGetter();
    virtual AbstractAlarmField& get(Device& dev) const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct AlarmMemberPtr
  : public AlarmGetter {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<AbstractAlarmField, T>::value,
                  "Member type is not an AbstractAlarmField");
public:
    explicit AlarmMemberPtr(T Device::*member)
      : m_member( member ) {}
    virtual AbstractAlarmField& get(Device& dev) const {
        return dev.*m_member;
    }
private:
    T Device::*m_member;
};

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<AlarmGetter> make_alarm_getter(T Device::*member) {
    std::unique_ptr<AlarmGetter> ptr(new AlarmMemberPtr<T>(member));
    return ptr;
}

// To populate:
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AlarmGetter>> alarmFieldCollection;
alarmFieldCollection.push_back(make_alarm_getter(&Device::hardwareMissingAlarm));
alarmFieldCollection.push_back(make_alarm_getter(&Device::hardwareErrorAlarm));
alarmFieldCollection.push_back(make_alarm_getter(&Device::badConfigAlarm));

// To use:
if (alarmFieldCollection[i]->get(*pDev).isRaised(pContext))
```

If it might be useful, you could also easily add an overload

```
virtual const AbstractAlarmField& get(const Device& dev) const;
```

Comment: The problem is that I have the same value for: &Device::hardwareMissingAlarm, &Device::hardwareErrorAlarm and
&Device::badConfigAlarm; that is 1. I think that is not correct isn't?

Comment: And isRaised is defined in AlarmField that inherits from AbstractAlarmField. And one device (pDev) can have several alarmFields.

Comment: A pointer to member can't be 1. But if you were trying to print them, they may have implicitly converted to `bool`, in which case, sure you would always get "1". You'll probably find that `&Device::hardwareMissingAlarm == &Device::hardwareErrorAlarm` is false.

Comment: Yes you are right they are different ;). So my problem is when I'm getting then the alarms with pDev->*pAF, how can I check that it is my alarmField or not?

Comment: I got this compilation error: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token in this line: std::unique_ptr<AlarmGetter> make_alarm_getter(T Device::*member) {

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking.  If you're able to get an `AbstractAlarmField` reference/pointer but can't figure out how to do something with it, maybe `AbstractAlarmField` needs another virtual method to make that possible.

Comment: Whoops, forgot `AlarmMemberPtr` should inherit `AlarmGetter`.  A SSCCE: http://ideone.com/cBJRN6

Comment: I have the same error  error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token in this line: std::unique_ptr<AlarmGetter> make_alarm_getter(T Device::*member)

Comment: The problem now I have is that when I want to call with pDevice->*pAF to a method for example (pDevice->*pAF).extractValues I'm calling to the method isRaised that is inherit from another class... so the pointer is wrong...

Comment: With your code I'm obtaining this compilation error: 'AbstractAlarmField' is an inaccessible base of 'AlarmField<AlarmField_DataType<4u>, 4u>'

Comment: "inaccessible base" usually means you are using private inheritance or protected inheritance, which are tricky things I avoid whenever possible.  I'm not sure what the compiler error at `make_alarm_getter` could be, unless `unique_ptr` is not available.  If that's the problem, you could replace every `std::unique_ptr<AlarmGetter>` with ordinary `AlarmGetter*` but then you have to be careful about copying or modifying the container and deleting them later.

Comment: Yes you are right I'm using boost instead of std for shared_ptr and is_base_of and now it is working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where can I find more information about pointer to members, I would like to understand totally this code, because I'm a little lost. It is working but I would like to understand how it works.